# Performance of 100M Row Table (Oracle 11g)

Tags: database, oracle, database-design

We are designing a table for ad-hoc analysis that will capture umpteen value fields over time for claims received. The table structure is essentially (pseudo-ish-code):

```
   table_huge (
     claim_key int not null,
     valuation_date_key int not null,
     value_1 some_number_type,
     value_2 some_number_type,
     [etc...],
     constraint pk_huge primary key (claim_key, valuation_date_key)
   );
```

All value fields all numeric. The requirements are: The table shall capture a minimum of 12 recent years (hopefully more) of incepted claims. Each claim shall have a valuation date for each month-end occurring between claim inception and the current date. Typical claim inception volumes range from 50k-100k per year.

Adding all this up I project a table with a row count on the order of 100 million, and could grow to as much as 500 million over years depending on the business's needs. The table will be rebuilt each month. Consumers will select only. Other than a monthly refresh, no updates, inserts or deletes will occur.

I am coming at this from the business (consumer) side, but I have an interest in mitigating the IT cost while preserving the analytical value of this table. We are not overwhelmingly concerned about quick returns from the Table, but will occasionally need to throw a couple dozen queries at it and get all results in a day or three.

For argument's sake, let's assume the technology stack is, I dunno, in the 80th percentile of modern hardware.

The questions I have are:

- Is there a point at which the cost-to-benefit of indices becomes excessive, considering a low frequency of queries against high-volume tables?
- Does the SO community have experience with +100M row tables and can
  offer tips on how to manage?
- Do I leave the database technology problem to IT to solve or should I
  seriously consider curbing the business requirements (and why?)?

I know these are somewhat soft questions, and I hope readers appreciate this is not a proposition I can test before building.

Please let me know if any clarifications are needed. Thanks for reading!

Comment: Are you REALLY expecting 100M+ rows?  Do you have a solid understanding of how the business can generate that much data?  You quote 50-100k claims per year, and need to store 12 years worth.  That's a much more reasonable 600K-1.2M rows.

Comment: 1. Define expected range for umpteen columns, please.
2. Will every column have every value populated for each row?

Comment: @JimGarrison Yes, yes, and yes. Remember this is not one row per claim, it's one row per claim per month that the claim has existed. E.g. 50k 12-year old claims would now occupy 50000x12X12=7.2M rows. And then there are the 11-year old claims, and so on.

Comment: @DamirSudarevic, table will have roughly 30 value columns. There will be no nulls in the table (but there might be a lot of zero values).

Comment: @andyholaday do field values repeat month-over-month? Is is expected for rows to repeat (other than date) frequently? Is it correct that an old claim would repeat itself without any data change, over-and-over again?

Comment: @DamirSudarevic, the answer is overwhelmingly yes. In fact, we expect about 95% "redundant" records where the only thing that changes is date. However, the nature of the analyses we do require these redundant records. We considered storing only the data points where something changed and building a view to reconstruct the entire data set, but we're concerned querying the view multiple times is worse than just storing the data all at once. I would love to have your thoughts about this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all: Expect this to "just work" if leaving the tech problem to IT - especially if your budget allows for an "80% current" hardware level.

I do have experience with 200M+ rows in MySQL on entry-level and outdated hardware, and I was allways positivly suprised.

Some Hints:

- On monthly refresh, load the table without non-primary indices, then create them. Search for the sweet point, how many index creations in parallell work best. In a project with much less date (ca. 10M) this reduced load time compared to the naive "create table, then load data" approach by 70%
- Try to get a grip on the number and complexity of concurrent queries: This has influence on your hardware decisions (less concurrency=less IO, more CPU)
- Assuming you have 20 numeric fields of 64 bits each, times 200M rows: If I can calculate correctly, ths is a payload of 32GB. Trade cheap disks against 64G RAM and never ever have an IO bottleneck.
- Make sure, you set the tablespace to read only

Comment: Thank you for these very helpful hints! FWIW the complexity of queries should be minimal; this is an expected outcome of our proposed structure. Concurrency will be limited and easily managed as only a couple/three superusers will use the table. I will share the indexing approach & hardware considerations with the technical folks. I would love to elaborate on _why_ all of this but I don't think this is the right venue (suggestions welcome). Meanwhile, I want to see what additional discussion emerges over the next day or two before I accept an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You could consider [**anchor modeling**](http://www.anchormodeling.com) approach to store changes only.

Considering that there are so many expected repeated rows, ~ 95%  --
bringing row count from 100M to only 5M, removes most of your concerns.

At this point it is mostly cache consideration, if the whole table
can somehow fit into cache, things happen fairly fast.

For "low" data volumes, the following structure is slower to query than a plain table; at one point (as data volume grows) it becomes faster. That point depends on several factors, but it may be easy to test. Take a look at this [**white-paper about anchor modeling**](http://www.anchormodeling.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/Anchor_Modeling_ER09_Presentation.pdf) -- see graphs on page 10.

[image]

In terms of anchor-modeling, it is equivalent to

[image]

The modeling tool has **automatic code generation**, but it seems that it currenty fully supports only MS SQL server, though there is ORACLE in drop-down too. It can still be used as a code-helper.

In terms of supporting code, you will need (minimum)

1. Latest perspective view (auto-generated)
2. Point in time function (auto-generated)
3. Staging table from which this structure will be loaded ([**see tutorial**](http://www.anchormodeling.com/?page_id=186) for data-warehouse-loading)
4. Loading function, from staging table to the structure
5. Pruning functions for each attribute, to remove any repeating values

It is easy to create all this by following auto-generated-code patterns.

Comment: This is really great! I've spent 90 minutes watching tutorials and I am mesmerized by the possibilities.

Comment: I just want you to know that while I accepted a different answer to this question, I really appreciate you taking the time and effort to respond. I think Anchor Modeling will play a role in future projects.

Answer (score 1):

With no ongoing updates/inserts, an index NEVER has negative performance consequences, only positive (by MANY orders of magnitude for tables of this size).

More critically, the schema is seriously flawed.  What you want is

```
Claim
    claim_key
    valuation_date

ClaimValue
    claim_key (fk->Claim.claim_key)
    value_key
    value
```

This is much more space-efficient as it stores only the values you actually have, and does not require schema changes when the number of values for a single row exceeds the number of columns you have allocated.

Comment: What you are proposing is essentially a simplified EAV. This _may_ be justified if there are many "holes" in the data (so the extra space needed for `ClaimValue.claim_key` and `value_key` is recuperated), but this doesn't seem to be the case here. NULLs are cheap to store. Also, I'm dubious about nonchalantly creating indexes even on mostly static data - there are caching interactions to consider. Create only indexes that you _know_ you need.

Comment: I appreciate the comments. As noted above, our table will have a value in every column on every row.

Answer (score 0):

Using partition concept & apply partition key on every query that you perform will save give the more performance improvements.

In our company we solved huge number of performance issues with the partition concept.

One more design solutions is if we know that the table is going to be very very big, try not to apply more constraints on the table & handle in the logic before u perform & don't have many columns on the table to avoid row chaining issues.